# Laravel Service Providers count and DI

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel

I understand how service prividers in Laravel works and how to use them. But I'm not sure about how to keep clean code, specificaly in count of method parameters. For example I have this route:

```
Route::post('/user/user-rooms', '\Modules\Administration\User\Services\UserRooms@rooms')
```

Where class looks like this:

```
public function rooms(Request $request, UserRulesInRoomsRepository $userRulesInRoomsRepository, RoomRepository $roomRepository)
{
    $user_rooms = $userRulesInRoomsRepository->findBy();
    $available_rooms = $this->availableRooms($userRulesInRoomsRepository, $roomRepository);
}

private function availableRooms(UserRulesInRoomsRepository $userRulesInRoomsRepository, RoomRepository $roomRepository)
{
    $userRules = $userRulesInRoomsRepository->getFilter();
    $rooms = $roomRepository->all();
}
```

I'm using repository `RoomRepository` only in method `availableRooms` but I need this repository already in method `rooms` because I want to keep dependecy injection.

I could use resolver `App::make(RoomRepository ::class)` instead parameter in `availableRooms` method but I think this is against DI pattern.

Another option would be save this repository to the class property and then call it from method but I think there is still problem that I have this parameter in `rooms` method even I'm using this repository only in one another method.

Hopefully I wrote it clear. What is best practice in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. As far as I can see you don't need to create a service provider class since the Laravel DI container will automatically new up your depedancies as required.

Comment: Repositories are already registered in service provider so I don't need to create one. My issue is about count of parameters in method where I want to keep DI and still using Laravel's service providers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a specific best practice - what you have looks OK, but I share your concern with the parameters in the method.

I would probably have Laravel inject the repository into the constructor of your controller, which should save the reference as a private property of the object, to be used by `availableRooms`.  The only reasons I would think of avoiding that are if there are just a small minority of public methods on the constructor that require a `RoomRepository` and `RoomRepository` is expensive to construct.